# Arguments from txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to load arguments from a text file with this syntax:

> a#b@c
>   a#b@c
>   a#b@c

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
with requests.session() as c:
    a = sys.argv[1]
    b = sys.argv[2]
    c = sys.argv[3]
try:
    ...
```

And I invoke the script like this:

```
$ python script.py a b c
```

But I want to modify my script so that it can run only once and consume every line of the argument text file.

Comment: And ? What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: if found this solution with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as my_file:
    print(my_file.read()) but im still dont know how to include the a#b@c syntax

Comment: You have tons of a, b, and c here, some of them probably represent same thing while others don't. What to you want in `sys.arg[1]`: the first line of the file, the character(s) preceding a sharp (`#`), and in that case what should be done with other lines? I may be stupid, but I could not guess it.

Comment: its just an example to explain the major problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the path to your arguments file as a command line argument to your script. Then open the file and extract `a`, `b`, and `c` from each line.

Here's an example:

```
def main(argv=None):
    # Get the file path.
    file_path = argv[1]

    # Open the file.
    with open(file_path) as argfile:
        for line in argfile:
            # Remove any leading or trailing whitespace.
            line = line.strip()

            # Extract a, b, and c.
            a = line.split('#')[0]
            b = line.split('#')[1].split('@')[0]
            c = line.split('@')[1]

            # Perform some action with a, b, and c.
```

Then you would invoke your script like this:

```
$ python script.py path/to/argfile.txt
```